# Ripping (legally) purchased DVD

Tags: optical-media, ripping

Over the time I've gathered some DVDs which I think would also be nice on our Mac Mini, which we use as NAS as well as for other stuff. We also use a streaming tool (Plex) so it would be nice to have the movies at one place.

I've made some attempts to rip DVDs using Handbrake, which is nice because it can get around the copyright thing. But in term of h/w ratio and quality it was horrible.

What I'm looking for is a DVD ripping tool that fits these criterias:

- Easy to use (good default settings or easy to change)
- Good quality in sound and video
- Options for file output (.mp4, .avi, .xxx)
- Velocity (shouln't take a whole night to do the magic :))
- Gets around the copyright
- Windows 7, Mac OS (pref) or Linux Ubuntu (on VM)
- Not expensive (> 15$ app store, elsewhere purchase with paysafe)

Assuming it is legal to make these copies for personal use and at least not considered illegal to go around the copyright where I live. Just things I love about Switzerland ;)

Comment: I'm not sure whether *Plex* can deal with ISO images (or the DVD folder structure). If it can, take a look at [DVDShrink](http://www.dvdshrink.org/). Long time ago I've used it last (MS free zone here for years), but except for the output format it would fully fit your needs (incl. selecting what the target should contain – i.e. leave those nasty "Disney Intros" out).

Comment: I'll take a look at it :)

Comment: You can also check this article about [WinX DVD ripper](http://www.raritysoft.com/reviews/the-winx-dvd-ripper-platinum-review-fab-or-flop) I think this is one of the best DVD ripping tool.

Answer (score 1):

For those who don't know how to start Handbrake:

Download HandBrake from [1]. Install handbrake. Now visit either [2 for 32 bit OS] or [3 for 64 bit OS] and it should autodownload the file. Now place this file into the program files folder for handbrake (dont put it into any of its subfolders). Now you can pop in your DVD and start ripping copy protected disks. 
[1] www.handbrake.fr 
[2] http://download.videolan.org/pub/libdvdcss/1.2.11/win32/libdvdcss-2.dll
[3] http://download.videolan.org/pub/libdvdcss/1.2.11/win64/libdvdcss-2.dll

Note: I do not support the illegal practice of DVD "Ripping" and do not do this. I wrote this based on lifehacker.com/how-to-rip-a-dvd-to-your-computer-5809765

Comment: Ripping DVDs is not illegal if it's for personal use, for example for backup purposes. It's obviously not legal to distribute it without explicit permission.